# Why do different Session Variables changes value when one session is updated?

Tags: c#, sql, session

**Background:**
Two buttons on a ASP.NET page.

***Button 1:***
Data is loaded into a DataSet.
2 Session variables, Session["a"] and Session["b"] are assigned the DataSet.

***Button 2:*** 
Session["a"] is cast to a DataSet. A record is deleted from the DataSet.

**Issue:**

BEFORE the AcceptChanges() function is called, both Session variables are changed to reflect the delete action (Rows.Count is 1 less). Why does this happen?

Surely the DataSet "ds" could not exist anymore?

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string StringContainingSQLConnection = @"server=someserver;database=Standby;uid=StandbyUser;password=pass;";
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from CoreData", StringContainingSQLConnection);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

        Session["a"] = ds;
        Session["b"] = ds;
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = ((DataSet)Session["a"]);

        foreach (DataRow drw in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            drw.Delete();
            ds.AcceptChanges();
            Session["a"] = ds;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I removed the conditional IF statement in the foreach loop for clarity and just delete the first record to prove the point.

Comment: Joshua's answer is correct. You probably want to set Session["b"] = ds.Copy() as it creates a new data set which is a copy of the original.

Comment: thanx momar. your .Copy() did the trick. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session a and Session b hold a reference to the location of the dataset in memory.  So essentially a and b are just two different names for the same thing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

If you wish for b to remain unchanged, you can create two datasets with the same initial data. Assign one set to a and one set to b.